# Proof of Clairaut's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Function $f(x,y)$ is defined in an open set $S$ containing $(0,0)$ in $\Bbb R^2$. Suppose $f_x$ and $f_{xy}$ exist, $f_{xy}$ is continuous in $S$. Define: $\Delta(h,w)=f(h,w)-f(h,0)-f(0,w)+f(0,0)$. Prove: $\lim_{(h,w)\to (0,0)} \frac {\Delta (h,w)}{hw}=f_{xy}(0,0)$.

I was thinking about applying mean value theorem but got stuck. Could someone please provide a proof following this idea in details? Thanks.

Comment: Don’t you also need the existence of $f_y$ and $f_{yx}$ and continuity of the latter for this?

Comment: @amd You are right that $f_x$, $f_y$ and $f_{xy}$ exist and are continuous, but we are trying to prove that $f_{yx}$ also exists and is equal to $f_{xy}$. It may be related to this link: https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/clairauts-theorem/

Comment: Then you’ve found the proof you’re looking for, haven’t you?

Comment: @amd Sorry, my bad, the question is not asking the whole proof of mixed partials are equal. I just edited it, so the link is not the answer.  $f_y$ is not defined here, and we only need to prove the above equality.

Comment: I see. Well, what you’re trying to prove is more or less one step of the larger proof, so you might be able to get ideas from that, anyway.